# Get index of current version in Rails PaperTrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I just don't seem to get it straight: How is it possible to receive / determine the index of the current version in `some_object.versions` using PaperTrail in RoR 4?

best and thanks,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

From PaperTrail documentation:

1. `some_object.version` returns the version this object was reified from, **or nil if it is live**.
2. `some_object.version.index` returns the current index if it is not nil.